# How to showDiff using pm.expect assertion in Postman

Tags: postman, assert

I am trying to show the when a pm.expect assertion fails the diff between the actual and expected. I see when there is a failure in the console the showDiff: false reported. I would like to set this flag to true. I have looked and searched for how to set this flag but I haven't been able to find the answer. I am guessing I just have looked in the right place. So to summarize I want to output to the console the assertion diff and I am looking for the flag or how to set the showDiff bool to true for my assertions in Postman. Thank you.

Comment: Could you show the `the showDiff: false` image? Which postman version do you use?

Comment: Please share your code and data.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an example of the console error. The service I am working with is down. However when I run this assert I see in the response when the assert fails it shows the assert details for expected vs actual with the showDiff=false flag.

assert I am using:

try{

    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("Value found in schema.");

}catch (e){
console.log(e);
throw Error;
}